# as a beginner, why do we use Temp tables?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I do not understand the temp tables, I am studying google data analytics certificate and this query meant to get this results

```
WITH longest_used_bike AS (
  SELECT
    bikeid,
    SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
  FROM 
    bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
  GROUP BY
    bikeid
  ORDER BY 
    trip_duration DESC
  limit 1
)
SELECT 
  trips.bikeid,
  trips.start_station_id, 
  COUNT(*) AS trip_ct 
FROM 
  longest_used_bike  as longest
  join bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips as trips
  on trips.bikeid = longest.bikeid
GROUP BY 
  bikeid,
  start_station_id
ORDER BY
  trip_ct DESC;
```

Another query I wrote returns exactly the same results as the previous one above

```
SELECT 
  trips.bikeid,
  trips.start_station_id, 
  COUNT(*) AS trip_ct 
FROM 
  bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips as trips
where trips.bikeid = "893"
  
GROUP BY 
  bikeid,
  start_station_id
ORDER BY
  trip_ct DESC;
```

and it is a lot simpler so why we use temp tables in this example.

Note: the dataset is austin_bikeshare in google bigquery-public-data

Here is a [screenshot of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk90J.png).

Comment: [A CTE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/recursive-ctes) is not a tempoary-table.

Comment: Also, you hardcoded some `"893"`. First query is more general.

Comment: also not getting the sum of duration, but simple enough to add.

Comment: @dai They say it is a temp table in the course but i knew now it is called cte, but my question was why did we use it if we mostly dont need it

Comment: I think the only point is about hardcoding, the first one I did not know that "893" was the bike with highest number of trips, the second one I already knew somehow @markalex

Comment: @AhmedAkramSerag You can re-use a CTE multiple times in a query just by using its name, whereas with an inner-query you'll need to repeat the entire query definition, and repetitive identical code is a common source of bugs (owing to human mistakes when making the same or similar changes to repetitive code).

Comment: @dai Thank You , now i get it a little more

Comment: but does using a temp table or a view is better tha the CTE , i feel difference between the 3 are very minor @Dai , what is the real difference between them?

Comment: @AhmedAkramSerag I'm not a Google BigQuery user, so I don't know if BigQuery has its own definitions of those terms, but in most RDBMSs there are very significant differences between them: a `VIEW` is a _permament_ named database object, and a temp-table is a _materialized_ table on-disk - both are very different to a CTE. It seems that you're only thinking of how they're all Codd _relation_-style objects that can be used in the `FROM` clause of a query, but remember that they're still very different.